# How to parse nested JSON with aeson

Tags: json, haskell

I am trying to parse JSON of the following form using aeson

```
{"field":{"name":"..."}}

or

{"tag":{"name":"..."}}

or

{"line":{"number":"..."}}
```

to construct the following data type

```
data Rule = Line Integer
          | Field L.ByteString
          | Tag L.ByteString
```

Unfortunately, I face two problems that I've not found solutions to, namely:

1. How do I parse nested JSON? Looking at the implementation of [(.:)](https://github.com/mailrank/aeson/blob/master/Data/Aeson/Types.hs#L258-261), it uses lookup to extract a specific key's value. I'm hesitant to do something like this as it seems to be relying too much on the specifics of how aeson implements things. Am I wrong in thinking this is an issue?
2. How do I use the correct data constructor based on which key is present in the JSON? All my efforts with <|> have led me nowhere.

I would post the code I've written thus far, but I haven't even gotten to the point where I have anything worth posting.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about the following?

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Control.Applicative
import           Data.Aeson
import           Data.Aeson.Types
import qualified Data.ByteString      as B
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as L
import qualified Data.Map             as M

data Rule = Line Integer
          | Field L.ByteString
          | Tag L.ByteString
          deriving Show

instance FromJSON Rule where
  parseJSON j = do
    o <- parseJSON j -- takes care of JSON type check
    case M.toList (o :: Object) of
      [("field", Object o')] -> Field <$> o' .: "name"
      [("tag",   Object o')] -> Tag   <$> o' .: "name"
      [("line",  Object o')] -> Line  <$> o' .: "number"
      _                      -> fail "Rule: unexpected format"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is exactly what I was looking for! I made a small change to the first two lines to make it `parseJSON (Object o) = case M.toList o of`, as well as add a separate ` parseJSON _          = mzero`.

Comment: @luke_randall, btw, I did use the `o <- parseJSON j` instead of `mzero` on purpose, as `mzero` doesn't provide any helpful information about what went wrong beyond a mere `"mzero"`, whereas `parseJSON` gives you error messages such as `"when expecting a Map Text a, encountered Array instead"`

Comment: Alright, that makes sense. Thanks for explaining your reasoning - I think I'll revert it.

Comment: @luke_randall: on the other hand, you could also replace your `mzero` with a more descriptive `fail "Rule: require JSON object but got something else"`... It's just my experience, that you want to have as much hints as possible wrt where the parsing failed if you have to debug your JSON parser, especially for more complex highly nested JSON documents...

Answer (score 6):

For this problem I created a helper function that looks up a key:

```
lookupE :: Value -> Text -> Either String Value
lookupE (Object obj) key = case H.lookup key obj of
        Nothing -> Left $ "key " ++ show key ++ " not present"
        Just v  -> Right v
loopkupE _ _             = Left $ "not an object"
```

and using it two functions that nest into objects:

```
(.:*) :: (FromJSON a) => Value -> [Text] -> Parser a
(.:*) value = parseJSON <=< foldM ((either fail return .) . lookupE) value

(.:?*) :: (FromJSON a) => Value -> [Text] -> Parser (Maybe a)
(.:?*) value = either (\_ -> return Nothing) (liftM Just . parseJSON)
                . foldM lookupE value
-- Or more simply using Control.Alternative.optional
-- (.:?*) value keys = optional $ value .:* keys
```

Only `lookupE` depends on the internal representation so it's easy to modify it, if that changes. Then `{"tag":{"name":"..."}}` is parsed as `v .:* ["tag", "name"]`. Note that it also works for empty lists - `v .:* []` is equivalent to `parseJSON v`.